# How to use prepare for query having LIKE clause

Tags: php, pdo

Please see the below code. This works fine with mysqli method, but is prone to sql injection. So I want to use prepared statements, but for LIKE I cant use it.

```
$t = strtolower($_POST['e']);
$search_exploded = explode(" ", $t);
$construct = '';
foreach ($search_exploded as $search_each) {
    $construct .= "AND title LIKE ? ";
}

$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM vdo WHERE 1 $construct ");
$query->execute(["%$search_each%"]);
$found = $query->rowCount();
if ($found == 0) {
    echo "NO Result Found";

} else {
    while ($row_id1 = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $title = $row_id1['title'];
    }  
}
```

Comment: `This works fine with mysqli method` mysqli has prepared statements too and they work exactly the same in this regard.  There is no "mysqli" method that is proper that allows for SQLInjection, just saying.

Answer (score 1):

You're only passing one parameter, the last of the array of search terms from your foreach loop.

```
$query->execute(["%$search_each%"]);
```

You need to use the entire array of terms instead.

```
$params = array_map(function($term) { return "%$term%"; }, $search_exploded);
$query->execute($params);
```